# error Property %s is not multi-line

Tags: python, html, django, datastore

My app is getting an error because of the `%s` (at least, this is what I think), but I don't know why. I have changed to django code to try to get data to the html template. The template is loading but the data is not being imported. The app does run locally but template is not loading data and on server I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1536, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1530, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ceemee11111/1.363684484611202021/helloworld.py", line 37, in get
    for greeting in greetings:
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 2314, in next
    return self.__model_class.from_entity(self.__iterator.next())
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 1442, in from_entity
    return cls(None, _from_entity=entity, **entity_values)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 974, in __init__
    prop.__set__(self, value)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 614, in __set__
    value = self.validate(value)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 2823, in validate
    raise BadValueError('Property %s is not multi-line' % self.name)
BadValueError: Property content is not multi-line
```

helloworld.py:

```
import cgi
import datetime
import urllib
import webapp2
import os

from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template



class Greeting(db.Model):
  """Models an individual Guestbook entry with an author, content, and date."""
  author = db.StringProperty()
  content = db.StringProperty(multiline=False)
  content2 = db.StringProperty(multiline=False)
  date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)


def guestbook_key(guestbook_name=None):
  """Constructs a Datastore key for a Guestbook entity with guestbook_name."""
  return db.Key.from_path('Guestbook', guestbook_name or 'default_guestbook')


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.response.out.write('<html><body>')
    guestbook_name=self.request.get('guestbook_name')

    greetings = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * "
                        "FROM Greeting "
                        "WHERE ANCESTOR IS :1 "
                        "ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10",
                        guestbook_key(guestbook_name))

    for greeting in greetings:
      if greeting.author:
        self.response.out.write(
            '<b>%s</b> wrote:' % greeting.author)
      else:
        self.response.out.write('An anonymous person wrote:')

      self.response.out.write(template.render('myhtml.html', {'guestbook_name': guestbook_name}))

class Guestbook(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
    guestbook_name = self.request.get('guestbook_name')
    greeting = Greeting(parent=guestbook_key(guestbook_name))

    if users.get_current_user():
      greeting.author = users.get_current_user().nickname()

    greeting.content = self.request.get('content')
    greeting.put()
    self.redirect('/?' + urllib.urlencode({'guestbook_name': guestbook_name}))


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                           ('/sign', Guestbook)],
                          debug=True)
```

myhtml.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <body>
      <form action="/sign?{{ guestbook_name }}" method="post">
       <div id="dataImput">
        <div><div><input type="text" name="content"</div>
        <div><div><input type="text" name="content2"</div>
      </div> 
      <script>
        document.write("<h1>This is heading</h1>");

      </script>
        <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Guestbook"></div>
      </form>
      <form>Guestbook name: <input value="{{ guestbook_name|escape }}" name="guestbook_name">
  <input type="submit" value="switch"></form>
  <hr>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks good find. I fixed it.  Dan

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about google app engine (but I know django). It seems there is a conflict between the types you are using in your model, and the form types you are using in your template:

[class StringProperty(verbose_name=None, multiline=False, ...)](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#StringProperty)

> If multiline is False, the value cannot include linefeed characters.
>   The djangoforms library uses this to enforce a difference between text
>   fields and textarea fields in the data model, and others can use it
>   for a similar purpose.

The actual error line from the traceback that is significant is:

```
BadValueError: Property content is not multi-line
```

"content" refers to your model property.

To me that indicates that you need to do one of the following options...

**1)** Change your model to accept multiline values being delivered from the textarea form fields:

```
class Greeting(db.Model):
...
  content = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
  content2 = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
...
```

**2)** Or change your textarea form fields to be text fields in your template:

```
    <div><input type="text" name="content"></div>
    <div><input type="text" name="content2"></div>
```

Comment: thanks. the multiline=True caused an error but multiline=false worked local. Still same problem on deployment. I will edit for changes.   Dan

Comment: I think you pasted in my syntax error version of the template fix. I was missing the `>` but I added them

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how i fixed this, but this code works as in the error is gone. I am posting this for anyone as information on the %s error only as the template still does not work

Dan

```
import cgi
import datetime
import urllib
import webapp2
import os

from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

    class Greeting(db.Model):
  """Models an individual Guestbook entry with an author, content, and date."""
  author = db.StringProperty()
  content = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
  content2 = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
  date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)


def guestbook_key(guestbook_name=None):
  """Constructs a Datastore key for a Guestbook entity with guestbook_name."""
  return db.Key.from_path('Guestbook', guestbook_name or 'default_guestbook')


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.response.out.write('<html><body>')
    guestbook_name=self.request.get('guestbook_name')

    greetings = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * "
                        "FROM Greeting "
                        "WHERE ANCESTOR IS :1 "
                        "ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10",
                        guestbook_key(guestbook_name))

    for greeting in greetings:
      if greeting.author:
        self.response.out.write(greeting.author)

      else:
        self.response.out.write('An anonymous person wrote:')
    self.response.out.write(template.render('myhtml.html', {'guestbook_name': guestbook_name}))



class Guestbook(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
    guestbook_name = self.request.get('guestbook_name')
    greeting = Greeting(parent=guestbook_key(guestbook_name))

    if users.get_current_user():
      greeting.author = users.get_current_user().nickname()

    greeting.content = self.request.get('content')
    greeting.put()
    self.redirect('/?' + urllib.urlencode({'guestbook_name': guestbook_name}))


 app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                           ('/sign', Guestbook)],
                          debug=True)
```

the myhtml.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <body>
      <form action="/sign?%s" method="post">
        <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
        <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Guestbook"></div>
      </form>
          <script>
          document.write("<h1>This is heading</h1>");

          </script>

    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is code that works to load template (for information only). Thanks everyone for getting me to this point in Django/Python coding. Couldn't have done it without you!

```
import cgi
import datetime
import urllib
import webapp2
import os

from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

class Greeting(db.Model):
  """Models an individual Guestbook entry with an author, content, and date."""
  author = db.StringProperty()
  content = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
  content2 = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
  date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)


def guestbook_key(guestbook_name=None):
  """Constructs a Datastore key for a Guestbook entity with guestbook_name."""
  return db.Key.from_path('Guestbook', guestbook_name or 'default_guestbook')


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    guestbook_name=self.request.get('guestbook_name')
    greetings_query = Greeting.all().ancestor(
        guestbook_key(guestbook_name)).order('-date')
    greetings = greetings_query.fetch(3)

    if users.get_current_user():
        url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
        url_linktext = 'Logout'
    else:
        url = users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)
        url_linktext = 'Login'

    template_values = {
        'greetings': greetings,
        'url': url,
        'url_linktext': url_linktext,
    }

    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))


class Guestbook(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
    guestbook_name = self.request.get('guestbook_name')
    greeting = Greeting(parent=guestbook_key(guestbook_name))

    if users.get_current_user():
      greeting.author = users.get_current_user().nickname()

    greeting.content = self.request.get('content')
    greeting.put()
    self.redirect('/?' + urllib.urlencode({'guestbook_name': guestbook_name}))


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                           ('/sign', Guestbook)],
                          debug=True)
```

and index.html code:

```
  <html>
    <body>
        {% for greeting in greetings %}
          {% if greeting.author %}
        <b>{{ greeting.author }}</b> wrote:
      {% else %}
        An anonymous person wrote:
      {% endif %}
      <blockquote>{{ greeting.content|escape }}</blockquote>
    {% endfor %}

<form action="/sign" method="post">
  <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
  <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Guestbook"></div>
</form>

<a href="{{ url }}">{{ url_linktext }}</a>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, change those lines:

```
content = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
content2 = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
```

for those ones:

```
content = db.TextProperty()
content2 = db.TextProperty()
```